# Upload multiple blobs to Azure Storage

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage

I have the following code to upload single blob to azure storage using `azure-storage-blob 12.5.0`.

Is there any way to pass a collection of byte arrays and do it in some kind of batch upload?

```
    public void store(final String blobPath, final String originalFileName, final byte[] bytes) {
        final BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(blobPath);
        final BlockBlobClient blockBlobClient = blobClient.getBlockBlobClient();
        try (ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)) {
            blockBlobClient.upload(inputStream, bytes.length, true);
        } catch (BlobStorageException | IOException exc) {
            throw new StorageException(exc);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to pass a collection of byte arrays and do it in some
>   kind of batch upload?

In V8 sdk, i found `uploadFromByteArray` method supports byte[] parameter.

```
CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference("helloV8.txt");

String str1 = "132";
String str2 = "asd";
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
os.write(str1.getBytes());
os.write(str2.getBytes());
byte[] byteArray = os.toByteArray();
blob.uploadFromByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
```

Test:

[image]

No such method could be found in V12 sdk,only `upload` method you used in your question.In fact,in above `uploadFromByteArray` method inside,it is `upload` method as well.

[image]

If you are referring upload multiple blobs in the batch,i'm afraid it it not supported in the official sdk except using `for` loop.About bulk writing,you could refer to the Azure CLI and AzCopy scenarios mentioned in this [document](https://ppolyzos.com/2018/11/12/different-options-to-upload-single-or-multiple-files-to-your-azure-storage-account/).